# installing tidyr package with my window laptop on my rstudio

Tags: r, tidyr

Am trying to install "tidyr" package on my R.studio (window)  but am getting the response Permission denied:

Error in install.packages: cannot open file 'C:/Users/OneCard/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/file3fdc2fbe1372/vctrs/help/figures/cast.png': Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

this has been sorted out. I was actually using an old version of both r and rstudio, so I have to uninstall the previous old app and reinstall the latest version of both r and rstudio after which I was able to instal my tidy package.

Thanks